# When I need to register ServiceStack license

Tags: servicestack, licensing

What is the use of the ServiceStack license? From what I read in the FAQ, in a WPF project where the client consumes ServiceStack services, it should be useless, even if this phrase

> When is a Developer License required?
> ***A developer license is required
> for each developer contributing .NET code to a project that references
> ServiceStack binaries (inc. transitive references)***. Licenses are not
> required for developers only building projects or only consuming
> ServiceStack Services.

leaves me some doubts.
If I use ServiceStack Client package should I register the license?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ServiceStack License unlocks the [built-in free quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) to enable unrestricted usage of ServiceStack's libraries.

As the [ServiceStack.Client libraries](https://docs.servicestack.net/clients-overview) doesn't contain any free quota restrictions, registering a License is not required.

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I'm searching